# Convert files from numerically sorted to alphabetically sorted

Tags: perl

I've got files sorted like the following, but they are not sorted by date.

```
1(1).jpg 
1(2).jpg 
1(3).jpg 
1(4).jpg 
. 
. 
.
```

I want to sort them to be

After i'm doing the following:

```
perl -e '$prefix="aaaa";map{rename "$_",$prefix++.".$1" if /.*\.(.*)/} <*>'
```

I get the following:

```
file 1 (1).jpg -> aaaa.jpg
file 1 (10).jpg -> aaab.jpg
file 1 (100).jpg -> aaac.jpg
file 1 (101).jpg -> aaad.jpg
```

I want it to be like:

```
1(1).jpg -> aaaa.jpg
1(2).jpg -> aaab.jpg
1(3).jpg -> aaac.jpg
1(4).jpg -> aaad.jpg
```

I guess this is because it considers the numeric sorting and not the alphabetical sorting.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to get the files numerically sorted into an array `@sorted_files`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw[ file(1).jpg file(2).jpg file(10).jpg];
my @sorted_files = map { $_->[1] } sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } map {
    my ($search_key) = $_ =~ /\((.*)\).jpg/;
    [$search_key, $_]
} @files;

say for @sorted_files;
```

**Output**:

```
file(1).jpg
file(2).jpg
file(10).jpg
```

Now you can apply your routine to convert them further.